# Can a Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra smartphone be connected to a 49-inch ultra-wide monitor?

Tags: external-display, samsung-galaxy-s-21

I want to start using my Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra as a computer. I'm also planning to buy an ultra-wide 49-inch monitor that I want to display the Samsung screen on using DEX mode. I want to connect the phone to the monitor using a USB-C cable. I'm talking about a monitor having screen dimensions of 5120x1440 or something very similar, e.g. [Philips 499P9H](https://www.coolblue.nl/en/product/826182/philips-499p9h.html).

I haven't purchased the monitor yet because I want to know first whether the built-in video card of the Samsung Galaxy S21 is powerful enough to handle the resolution of a 49-inch ultrawide screen.

Does anyone know whether this smartphone can handle such a widescreen? It needs to be able to fill the entire screen, not just part of it.

Comment: According to the Samsung website it depends on the phone and the adapters wherpt resolutions and aspect ration are supported. May be you should first go to an electronic market and test it out with a 4k TV or other displays that are available if this works at all. Second check the spec of the used adapter regarding HDMI version and maximum resulution for the used HDM version.

Comment: @Robert it works with a 4K monitors and a usb C to HDMI cable. I know i could go to an electronics store as well. But i wanted to know if someone on here already knew whether using this smartphone with an UW monitor is possible or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It **didn't work** with my Samsung 32:9 1080p monitor. Specifically, invoice says

> MONITOR SAMSUNG LED 49”
> LC49J890DKUXEN

Monitor kept displaying `Not optimal, use 3840×1080 60Hz`. I tried both HDMI using dongle, and direct USB-C connection.

With traditional full HD monitors I'm getting lock screen displayed all right, tested on two, both using HDMI dongle.

This is only one data point, so it is possible that other pairs would work.